Acrobat JavaScript: Popup "Are you sure?" dialog box?
I have a button I created for deleting a template-generated PDF page in Acrobat using the following script:
this.deletePages(this.pageNum, this.pageNum) ;

I would like to add a popup warning, so that when the user clicks the button they are warned first before the page is deleted. e.g., "Delete current page? This action is not reversible."
OK proceeds, Cancel cancels the action.
I feel this is very possible, but a bit outside my JavaScript knowledge.

Java isn't related to Javascript. I'm not familiar with what all JS is compatible with Adobe, but you might look into using confirm.

OP did say that the action was not reversible, so it seems "undo" is not an option here.

if(app.alert("Delete current page? This action is not reversible.",3,1)==1)
{this.deletePages(this.pageNum,this.pageNum)}

The above did it if anyone stumbles upon this. Thanks to the commenters for their input/direction.

How does alert() give you options for OK and Cancel? There's no "going back" from an alert. It's just a message.
